# $_SESSION up all $_POST variables?

Tags: php, syntax, post, while-loop

Is there any way to do some kind of `while()` for each post variable and session it up... like in mysql

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo($row['name'];
}
```

But to get this result with the $_POST

```
while($_POST){
$_SESSION['BLA'] = $_POST['BLA'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
echo $key . ' = ' .$value. ' <br />';
 // do whatever you want to do with these variables
}
```

Or

just for example, if you just want to put all of those in $_POST into $_SESSION

```
$_SESSION['MyPost'] = $_POST;
```

Comment: This method is preferable as it means your post information is stored in a sub-array, so that it won't replace any other SESSION elements you may already have present.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $i=>$v){
    $_SESSION[$i] = $_POST[$i];
}
```